# Using inp() on 16Bit Dos 5with Turbo C++ 3.0

Tags: c++, io, dos

First off I'd like to say that I know this is a really outdated question.  That,s probably why I can't find any information through google.  (or I'm just worse at searching than I'd like to admit! haha.)  All the results pretty much tell me that `inp()` & `outp()` are useless on modern systems because the kernel handles all input and output rather than the program.  I'm running 16 Bit Dos from a 486 machine and I've been able to use `outp()` with my parallel port perfectly.  I like 16 Bit Dos, and I'm not interested in learning a "new and improved" way of doing this on NT era systems and higher (at least not right now).

With that cleared up --

My question is in regards to `inp()`.  I have an old hardcopy manual that says you pass a single variable, the port address, to `inp()`.  In this case I assume that since I use `0x378` as the port for `outp()`, I'd use it for `inp()` as well.  Since I haven't programmed to accept external input before, I wasn't sure what type of value I'd get from a simple on/off switch so I wrote this quick code to grab all new values-

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main(void){
    clrscr();

    int input;
    int buff = 0;

    restart:

    input = inp(0x378);

        if(input != buff){
        cout<<input;
        buff = input;
        }

    goto restart;

}
```

I just used 'buff' so that it wouldn't keep spitting '255' out over and over and possibly cover up a different value when power was applied to an input pin.  Needless to say, the only value that got printed was '255'.

When I write a program to output data to the "D" pins on the parallel port, I send a hex code to the port that corresponds with the desired output...  Right now I am dealing with the "S" pins on the parallel port for input.  Should I be getting a hex code back into the program?

Also, I went into the BIOS and made sure that the mode for the parallel port was in/out, not just out.  After finding out that I had two modes, my wave of excitement quickly got crushed with the same lousy '255' output.

Any information to point me in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `inp` does exactly what you think it does, so you don't need advice about that.  You need advice about parallel-port programming. Here's my google search, which brought up a ton of useful info: http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pc+parallel+port+programming

Comment: Right, Turbo C++ 3.0 was released to support Windows 3.0. Hardly what you'd expect in this millennium...

Comment: @Rob I have searched many searches on google on parallel port programming, and am quite familiar with what's out there.  Most are directed towards using libraries to work with NT and newer systems, very few are demonstrating outp().  What I'm looking for is the most basic C++ implementation of inp() to detect any input whatsoever. So in psuedo code -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks thorough: http://www.beyondlogic.org/spp/parallel.htm

Also, make sure you configure the parallel port in the BIOS for Bidirectional mode.  Other possibilities are Output Only, EPP and ECP modes, but Bidirectional will work best for what you are trying to do.  You'll need bit 5 in 0x37a to control the direction of the port.  Also, the base address of the port you are using might not be 0x378...There are locations in memory to get the base addresses of LPT1-LPT4 (The BIOS setup page may tell you as well.)

Comment: Right... I actually saw this page and lost it, definitely the most helpful answer so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In this case I assume that since I use
>   0x378 as the port for outp()

Don't. Ports may be unidirectional (although for LPT it is not the case for the best of my memory).

In any case, it's hard to know what the problem is without knowing what's connected to the port. In general, there's a control register (port + 2) and status register (port +1) which you should be using to control the actual controller and read its status. I really haven't dealt with real-mode PC programming for years, but for the embedded devices I work on, the input/output ports have to be used in conjunction with the control/status registers, not blindly.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish in the first place? The parallel port is not a good bidirectional channel. If you want point-to-point communication between computers (or arbitrary device to computer), the serial port with a null modem cable would be a much better choice. Or USB. Or, um, the network. You know, the Ethernet kind.

That said, the assumption that one I/O port (in the inp()/outp() sense) corresponds to one physical port (serial/parallel/whatever) is WRONG, WRONG, WRONG. Specifically for parallel, there's a data register and a control register, and transmission involves placing the byte onto the data register and flipping a bit in the control register. Not sure how does receiving work - look up the specs. For the serial, the protocol is even more involved.

There's a reason why modern OS's, with their driver/userland model, have evolved. Even under DOS, there are interrupts that abstract the nitty-gritty of port interaction. Read up on BIOS interrupts.

Comment: Here's the thing...  I use outp() all the time to program a panel of relays.  I send a hex code to the port and the hex code determines which relays kick on.  0x00 is off, 0x01 is the first one, etc...  I've done this for a long time. It's a simple and reliable way of doing what I need.  I realize this may be an incorrect method, but it works.  Now, my question to you is this:  Is "listening" for an input going to be any different?  Is this where I will NEED to use the data register and control register actively to achieve some sort of input from the port?

Comment: @thelp: nowadays, we'd use USB HID for that. I'm not saying the old method is incorrect, but the new method surely is far more convenient.

Comment: For that particular panel of relays the protocol is that simple. For parallel ports, it's not. Thoughtful spec reading is advised.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you means how to input signal through the LPT1? 
For first you should read a tutorial of interfacing...
[LPT1 interfacing sample](https://megagames3999.wordpress.com/2019/12/18/lpt-1-interface/)
 You will find that the pin 11
is related the input. Well that pin 11 is related the register 0x378+1.

About code you have to import those libs and use that command to import

```
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<bios.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<dos.h>
    #define LPT1      0x378

    void main (){
...
    unsigned int x = inportb(LPT1+1);
...
}
```