# How compiler knows if a pointer address in C is port mapped or RAM?

Tags: c, io

I know that port mapped IO are accessed thorugh in/out CPU instructions and memory (& memory mapped registers) are accessed through load/store CPU instructions (similar to memory). But, with a pointer in C code, how compiler knows if a address is port mapped IO register or memory and then inserts the correct CPU instructions?

**Example:**

```
uint16_t const* uart_reg = 0x8000c000;
uint16_t const* ram_addr = 0x4000c000;

*uart_reg = 0x1;
*ram_addr = 0x12;
```

Comment: It does not. What CPU instructions more than a simple write does it need to emit?

Comment: The *compiler* doesn't know. All it does is generate code to read from or write to that specific address. It's the hardware itself that handles it, or possibly the operating system.

Comment: If you need IO port mapped IO you need to use special functions from the compiler to generate the port access instructions.

Comment: Some compilers use different *address spaces* to disambiguate between RAM and port I/O (and, on a harvard architecture, program memory). They just add fixed offsets to the pointer values.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis instructions to read/write to an IO port are different from read/write to memory. E.g. IN/OUT instead of generig MOV/LD/... instructions

Comment: @Gerhardh true - I suppose I wrote the comment with only userspace in mind.

Answer (score 4):

If you have non-memory-mapped I/O, you're not going to be able to access it from C as if it were memory.

You must use some platform-specific trickery to get the proper I/O instructions. This is a pain, and might be one reason why modern hardware seems to favor memory-mapped I/O.

C compilers for platforms with port-mapped I/O had to include this, see for instance the [`inp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539345/using-inp-on-16bit-dos-5with-turbo-c-3-0) function in the old Turbo C++ for DOS.

Comment: While not having to use special instructions played a part, I suspect much of the reason for switching to memory-mapped I/O was the rise of larger address spaces and better options for "glue" logic (e.g. FPGAs/ASICs). For a Z80, you would need to "fully decode" the (few) memory-mapped addresses to avoid large holes in the address space, and that took lots of 7400-series chips. With GBs of memory space, you might only partially decode addresses (so `0xF0xxxxx1` works, for any `x`). If you still want to fully-decode, you can do it all in the FPGA/ASIC.

Answer (score -1):

Two steps:

1. Install the correct toolchain for your target hardware.
2. Use provided header files with all the necessary properly dome definitions

For example if you want to program ARM STM uC bare metal gcc compiler - use `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and tools. Use header CMSIS header files provided by STM & ARM (usually they are already included if you  choose a "ready made" toolchain)

Example declarations and definitions (only for ADC1):

```
#define FLASH_BASE            ((uint32_t)0x08000000U) /*!< FLASH base address in the alias region */
#define CCMDATARAM_BASE       ((uint32_t)0x10000000U) /*!< CCM(core coupled memory) data RAM base address in the alias region     */
#define SRAM_BASE             ((uint32_t)0x20000000U) /*!< SRAM base address in the alias region */
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000U) /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region */
#define SRAM_BB_BASE          ((uint32_t)0x22000000U) /*!< SRAM base address in the bit-band region */
#define PERIPH_BB_BASE        ((uint32_t)0x42000000U) /*!< Peripheral base address in the bit-band region */
#define AHB3PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x10000000U)
#define ADC1_BASE             (AHB3PERIPH_BASE + 0x00000000U)

#define ADC1                ((ADC_TypeDef *) ADC1_BASE)

#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define   __I     volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#else
  #define   __I     volatile const       /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#endif
#define     __O     volatile             /*!< Defines 'write only' permissions */
#define     __IO    volatile             /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions */

/* following defines should be used for structure members */
#define     __IM     volatile const      /*! Defines 'read only' structure member permissions */
#define     __OM     volatile            /*! Defines 'write only' structure member permissions */
#define     __IOM    volatile            /*! Defines 'read / write' structure member permissions */
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t ISR;              /*!< ADC Interrupt and Status Register,                 Address offset: 0x00 */
  __IO uint32_t IER;              /*!< ADC Interrupt Enable Register,                     Address offset: 0x04 */
  __IO uint32_t CR;               /*!< ADC control register,                              Address offset: 0x08 */
  __IO uint32_t CFGR;             /*!< ADC Configuration register,                        Address offset: 0x0C */
  uint32_t      RESERVED0;        /*!< Reserved, 0x010                                                         */
  __IO uint32_t SMPR1;            /*!< ADC sample time register 1,                        Address offset: 0x14 */
  __IO uint32_t SMPR2;            /*!< ADC sample time register 2,                        Address offset: 0x18 */
  uint32_t      RESERVED1;        /*!< Reserved, 0x01C                                                         */
  __IO uint32_t TR1;              /*!< ADC watchdog threshold register 1,                 Address offset: 0x20 */
  __IO uint32_t TR2;              /*!< ADC watchdog threshold register 2,                 Address offset: 0x24 */
  __IO uint32_t TR3;              /*!< ADC watchdog threshold register 3,                 Address offset: 0x28 */
  uint32_t      RESERVED2;        /*!< Reserved, 0x02C                                                         */
  __IO uint32_t SQR1;             /*!< ADC regular sequence register 1,                   Address offset: 0x30 */
  __IO uint32_t SQR2;             /*!< ADC regular sequence register 2,                   Address offset: 0x34 */
  __IO uint32_t SQR3;             /*!< ADC regular sequence register 3,                   Address offset: 0x38 */
  __IO uint32_t SQR4;             /*!< ADC regular sequence register 4,                   Address offset: 0x3C */
  __IO uint32_t DR;               /*!< ADC regular data register,                         Address offset: 0x40 */
  uint32_t      RESERVED3;        /*!< Reserved, 0x044                                                         */
  uint32_t      RESERVED4;        /*!< Reserved, 0x048                                                         */
  __IO uint32_t JSQR;             /*!< ADC injected sequence register,                    Address offset: 0x4C */
  uint32_t      RESERVED5[4];     /*!< Reserved, 0x050 - 0x05C                                                 */
  __IO uint32_t OFR1;             /*!< ADC offset register 1,                             Address offset: 0x60 */
  __IO uint32_t OFR2;             /*!< ADC offset register 2,                             Address offset: 0x64 */
  __IO uint32_t OFR3;             /*!< ADC offset register 3,                             Address offset: 0x68 */
  __IO uint32_t OFR4;             /*!< ADC offset register 4,                             Address offset: 0x6C */
  uint32_t      RESERVED6[4];     /*!< Reserved, 0x070 - 0x07C                                                 */
  __IO uint32_t JDR1;             /*!< ADC injected data register 1,                      Address offset: 0x80 */
  __IO uint32_t JDR2;             /*!< ADC injected data register 2,                      Address offset: 0x84 */
  __IO uint32_t JDR3;             /*!< ADC injected data register 3,                      Address offset: 0x88 */
  __IO uint32_t JDR4;             /*!< ADC injected data register 4,                      Address offset: 0x8C */
  uint32_t      RESERVED7[4];     /*!< Reserved, 0x090 - 0x09C                                                 */
  __IO uint32_t AWD2CR;           /*!< ADC  Analog Watchdog 2 Configuration Register,     Address offset: 0xA0 */
  __IO uint32_t AWD3CR;           /*!< ADC  Analog Watchdog 3 Configuration Register,     Address offset: 0xA4 */
  uint32_t      RESERVED8;        /*!< Reserved, 0x0A8                                                         */
  uint32_t      RESERVED9;        /*!< Reserved, 0x0AC                                                         */
  __IO uint32_t DIFSEL;           /*!< ADC  Differential Mode Selection Register,         Address offset: 0xB0 */
  __IO uint32_t CALFACT;          /*!< ADC  Calibration Factors,                          Address offset: 0xB4 */

} ADC_TypeDef;
```

---

and it expands to: `((ADC_TypeDef *) ((((uint32_t)0x40000000U) + 0x10000000U) + 0x00000000U))`

It is not worth to do it manually.

Comment: Where does this answer adress "Port mapped IO"?